# What can be removed from Android Tablet?

Tags: applications, tablet, lagging, optimization

I was recently given a roverpad tesla 10.1 tablet :

(https://www.imei.info/phonedatabase/16842-roverpad-tesla-101/)

It is total garbage as a tablet but I would like to use as a controller for a mini robot via an android app (via bluetooth). So in order to get a better experience I would like to remove all the unused features (multi apps ? multi screens ? logging screens).

Right now even after doing a 'one click root' = KingRoot (but it is not a total root, so I can delete apps but cannot change the OS) and deleting all the non system apps from the tablet it is still quite laggy (but battery life is way better).

Would you have some advice on how I can optimize it for one single usage (running an app to control a robot via bluetooth) without routing it (well if someone knows a way to root this poor soul, that would be quite awesome).

Thank you in advance,

Artiom

Comment: What do you mean with "can not change the OS"? Please tell us exactly the command you are trying and the error message.

Comment: I just meant that it is a kingroot type of root, so I can't change the OS as I only have root permission for given apps, in order to boot on a new OS I would have to do a permanent root, which I could manage to do.

Answer (score -1):

You can gain root access depending on your Android version using various methods on that device.

**Try these first,**

- [FramaRoot Application](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/framaroot/root-framaroot-one-click-apk-to-root-t2130276)
- [TowelRoot Application](https://towelroot.com)

  **Then, only if they failed !**
- [KingRoot 4.9.6 Application](http://apk15-storage.com/?s=5a72d7ef331fe49821ce5e729c60fa4b)

> Kingroot will root %99 of Android device's running below Android 5.0, however it is annoying to remove it, that's why i suggest FramaRoot first.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already use KingRoot (that's what I called a 'one click root' sorry if it's not the appropriate name), using it I already deleted all the base app package on the tablet, such as play market or google chrome. But I cannot change the OS using such type of rooting.